# Sox: silencing the first 100msec of audio file then fading in

Tags: sox

With sox, I need to silence (ie. mute) the first 100msec (or 4800 samples) of a multichannel audio file, then commence a rapid fade-in over 40 msecs. I've not been able to work out how to do it. Do fade-ins have to be linear with sox or are there other options?

Suggestions please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Muting and fading within the audio stream are not directly supported, but in your case, you can do it in these steps:

1. Remove the first part of the audio with `trim 0.1`. (You could write `trim 4800s` as well, if your sample rate is 48000 Hz.)
2. Do the fade-in on what is now the start of the audio (0.10–0.14 of the original audio), with `fade 0.04`.
3. Prepend the audio with silence to make up for what you removed, with `pad 0.1`.

So, the complete command is:

```
sox infile outfile trim 0.1 fade 0.04 pad 0.1
```

By default, `fade` uses a logarithmic fade curve starting at –100 dB. However, you can choose a different curve by specifying a letter directly after `fade`, as in `fade t 0.04`. There are `t` for linear, `q` for quarter-sine, `h` for half-sine, `p` for parabolic, as well as `l` for logarithmic (the default, but in case you want to make it explicit).